# How to properly add a UITableView inside a nav and tab controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a navigation setup where at the top there is a UITabBarController. I then have a tab, which is instantiated by creating a UIViewController placed into a UINavigationController like so:

```
UIViewController *testVC = [UIViewController new]; // Has UITableView as subview
UINavigationController *testNavVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:testVC];

[self setViewControllers:@[testNavVC]];
```

The problem that arrises is with the UITableView inside the testVC UIViewController. The table displays properly at the top and is correctly situated underneath the UINavController's nav bar. When you scroll the table view to the bottom, however, the final rows in the table view will be cut off at the bottom of the screen. I found out that I can set the bottom content inset to 100(value will differ based on row height) to correctly display the content. I don't feel like I should need to do that though, and am looking for a better solution.

How can I properly add a UITableView that is nested in this way?

As a side note this all works correctly when using a UITableViewController rather than a UIViewController with the added UITableView. In my case I am needing to use the latter option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of my code was done programmatically and the problem ended up being that I setup the UITableView with the views frame. I switched it over to use autolayout instead and it worked great!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adjust UITableView bottom inset without hardcoding, by using bottomLayoutGuide property:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, self.bottomLayoutGuide.length, 0.0);
```

It indicates lowest vertical extent for content, and can be used from iOS 7.

As an alternative you can create bottom NSLayoutConstraint for UITableView with this value.